# Mobile first Server 8 queries

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-8, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I new new Mobile first platform and websphere application server(WAS)

I installed mobile first server (MobileFirst-8.0.0.0)on my system and I am assuming the mobile first runs on WAS

I am having following queries.

1. How to deploy .war file in mobile first server 8 as it's console which is run 9080 port doesn't have option to deploy war file as it only have option to deploy adapter ?
2. If a deploy adapter on the mobile first server, at what location on the server i find the file ?
3. If war deployed on websphere then still how i use mobile first sevices like push, analytics.
4. Can i use spring and hibernate while developing adapters or any other ibm options are available in contrast to spring and hibernate.
5. As I am new to ibm products, want to know what are the topics and product need to learn before i start development.

Kindly share

Answer (score 1):

Before all, you **should google**.

> How to deploy .war file in mobile first server 8 as it's console which
>   is run 9080 port doesn't have option to deploy war file as it only
>   have option to deploy adapter ?

In v8.0 you no longer need to deploy .war files to the underlying application servers. Certainly not in the developer edition.

You either start a server instance on Bluemix, or use the DevKit for local installations. Then, you either create native apps or Cordova apps - using the native tools or Cordova CLI, and develop adapters using Maven.

Learn more in the Knowledge Center and find additional documentation and tutorials in the developer center.

> If a deploy adapter on the mobile first server, at what location on
>   the server i find the file ?

The adapter file (.adapter) is deployed to the MobileFirst database.

> If war deployed on websphere then still how i use mobile first sevices
>   like push, analytics.

Yes, those are services that are available to you out of the box. Learn more in the knowledge center and developer center.

> Can i use spring and hibernate while developing adapters or any other
>   ibm options are available in contrast to spring and hibernate.

Yes, you can use these technologies. And adapter is a JAX-RS application and so you can integrate a

> As I am new to ibm products, want to know what are the topics and
>   product need to learn before i start development.

Product documentation is available in the following websites:

- IBM Knowledge Center: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/wl_welcome.html
- MobileFirst Foundation Developer Center: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/all-tutorials/